# How do I check to see if array slot is empty?

Tags: php

In the example below $list is an array created by user input earlier in the code, and some slots the user has input nothing. I want to skip the empty items, so the commas aren't created in the output.

```
$list = array("first", "second", "", "", "fifth", "sixth", "", "");


foreach ($list as $each){$places .= $each . ",";}
```

results
first,second,,,fifth,sixth,,,

result I want
first,second,fifth,sixth

Got a solution. It looks like this:

```
$list = array_filter($list);
$places .= implode (",",$list);
```

Comment: `$list = array_filter($list);`

Comment: Also, use `implode` instead of this `foreach` loop.

Comment: @MarkBaker I need to buy you a beer.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the empty values, you can use

```
$list = array_filter($list);
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
    [4] => fifth
    [5] => sixth
)
```

*Source: [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297128/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-array-slot-is-empty#comment28575838_19297128)*

Comment: WOOT!! This is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter), when passed no second parameter, will remove any empty entries. From there you can proceed as normal:

```
foreach (array_filter($list) as $each){
  $places .= $each . ',';
}
```

Though you can also use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) if you're just turning it in to a CSV:

```
$places .= implode(',', array_filter($list));
```

**Side Note** Though in this case `array_filter` may work, it is worth noting that this removes entries that result in a ["falsy" result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). That is to say:

```
$list = array_filter(array('foo','0','false',''));
// Result:
// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(3) "foo"
//   [2]=>
//   string(5) "false"
// }
```

So be careful. If the user could potentially be entering in numbers, I would stick with comparing `empty`. Alternatively you can use the second parameter of `array_filter` to make it more explicit:

```
function nonEmptyEntries($e)
{
  return ((string)$e) !== '';
}
$list = array_filter($list, 'nonEmptyEntries');
// result:
//array(3) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(3) "foo"
//  [1]=>
//  string(1) "0"
//  [2]=>
//  string(5) "false"
//}
```

(Note that the `0` entry is kept, which differs from a blanket `array_filter`)

Comment: In this case, I am the user inputing the information. But in the future, I may need to go in this direction. Thank you for the insight. :)